# Windows Insider Preview stuck on 17677

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bsod, windows-10-upgrade

Currently I run Windows Insider builds on my second pc. The recent days it tries to update the build but everytime it reboots a GSOD will appear with a System Service Exception caused by "afd.sys". I tried the Windows update fixit tool and also did a sfc scan. Nothing helped. After the GSOD it needs manual reboot then recovers back automatically to 17677 and will download the next Insider build again.

Comment: What. Exactly is a GSOD?  You tagged this question as BSOD? Have you used windbg to determine the cause of the BSOD?

Comment: @Ramhound actually a green screen of death. The one that appears on preview builds

Comment: @Ramhound in Insider Builds the BSOD screen is green. m0ddixx, have you tried downloading the last Insider via ISO and manually upgrade?

Comment: You should still be able to use windbg to analyze the crash though.  Wasn't aware they changed the color though.

Comment: this was a bug, [that Microsoft fixed in Build 17692](https://superuser.com/a/1331403/174557)

Comment: have you tried the new Insider version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft fixed the issue in [Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17692](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/06/14/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17692/)

> **General changes, improvements, and fixes for PC**
>
> - We fixed an issue resulting in some Insiders recently experiencing a bug check (green screen) with the error **SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION** in
>     **afd.sys**.

So check again for new updates and download the last Insider Preview.

Comment: The author might have to wait until a new Windows Insider Preview ISO is released.  The only one that currently exists is for build 17127.  Since build 17692 was released today it might be awhile.

Comment: no, he can get this version from WU or [build his own ISO via script](https://uup.rg-adguard.net/)